# Test the service in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

This is the service I have :

```
@Service
public class UserInfoService {

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoServiceClient UserInfoServiceClient; // Call another Rest API

    public ResponseEntity<ResponseUserInfoData> sendUserInfo(String UserId) throws RuntimeException {

        ResponseUserInfoData responseUserInfoData = new ResponseUserInfoData();

           //Get the body from the User service client

            UserServiceDTO UserServiceDTO = UserInfoServiceClient.sendResponse(UserId).getBody();

            //Set the values of responseUserInfoData

            Optional<UserServiceDTO> UserServiceDTOOptional = Optional.ofNullable(UserServiceDTO);

            if (UserServiceDTOOptional.isPresent()) {

                UserServiceDTOOptional.map(UserServiceDTO::getId).ifPresent(responseUserInfoData::setid);

            }
            else return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();

        }


    }
```

I have to test it. I'm new to JUnit testing. I want to test the following points:

1. To check  if the service return the response entity
2. To check if the get and set method works

This is what I started?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private UserInfoService UserInfoService;

    @Mock
    private UserInfoServiceClient UserInfoServiceClient;

    @Mock
    private UserServiceDTO UserServiceDTO;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserInfoData() throws IOException{

        UserInfoService.sendUserInfo("ABC");
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito is useful to mock the dependencies of the service so that you can test all the code path in you service. In your case you will want to stub the call to serInfoServiceClient.sendResponse(UserId) and have it return a specific UserServiceDTO for each test case.

The test file looks like it is set up correctly, you only need to mock the method to give you the result you need for the particular test, for example

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private UserInfoService UserInfoService;

    @Mock
    private UserInfoServiceClient UserInfoServiceClient;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserInfoData() throws IOException{
        final String userId = "123";
        // The mocked return value should be set up per test scenario
        final UserServiceDto dto = new UserServiceDto();
        final ResponseEntity<UserServiceDTO> mockedResp = new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);

        // set up the mock service to return your response
        when(UserInfoServiceClient.sendResponse(userId)).thenReturn(mockedResp);

        // Call your service
        ResponseEntity<ResponseUserInfoData> resp = UserInfoService.sendUserInfo(userId);

        // Test the result
        Assert.isNotNull(resp);
    }
}
```

There are also other ways to mock the dependencies using Mockito. I suggest going through the quick start of https://site.mockito.org/

Comment: if dto is null (I haven't initialized it with values) then it show that the test is failed. But I'm getting NullPointerException. The service throws Runtime Excpetion and return null. @Bradley Meintjes

Comment: @bkumar that makes sense because of the call to getBody() in your service. The return type of the mock should then likely be `ResponseEntity<ResponseUserInfoData>`. Edited answer accordingly